# Tensorflow dataset.map() giving type error when method argument is given

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following along with a tensor flow tutorial and I have been creating a WindowGenerator class with the following methods being a part:

```
   def split_window(self, features):
    inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
    labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
    if self.label_columns is not None:
        labels = tf.stack(
            [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
            axis=-1)

    # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
    # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
    inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
    labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

    return inputs, labels

  WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window
```

and

```
  def make_dataset(self, data):
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=32,)

    ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

    return ds
  WindowGenerator.make_dataset = make_dataset
```

the line "ds = ds.map(self.split_window)" gives the error "labels = tf.stack(
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable".

I believe the map function requires an argument that is a function, and I do not see how ds is impacted by the function "self.split_window", what is the true nature of the error?

Comment: `ds = ds.map(self.split_window)` calls the `split_window` function defined above. I have reproduced the entire notebook and it ran without errors. It looks like somewhere the square brackets got interchanged by round brackets and hence the error. You can add your **gist** so that it can be decoded further.